# Sitecore 10 Helixbase Serialization Error - There is a dependency loop in your module dependencies

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

Using Helixbase as a starting point, I have created a helix solution and an faq feature module.  The faq content items have serialized as well as the various templates and layouts.

After adding a few more modules, I started getting this error

```
PS D:\sitecore> dotnet sitecore ser pull
There is a dependency loop in your module dependencies Unresolved modules: (lists all modules)
```

I double checked the solution and there aren't any dependencies between the projects that violate the Helix pattern.

Is there something in Sitecore 10 that I may have missed when creating the VS modules?  What are the possible causes for this error?

Answer (score 1):

This happens within the Sitecore CLI during the serialization process to properly setup the order of serialization operations and protect the serialization processes.

Within the Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Configuration.ModuleDependencyResolver class there is a check to determine dependency counts and if it exceeds a count of 20,000 this error is raised.

I suggest checking any "references" defined in serialization modules.